# should office addin sign out O365 Account When it is authenticated base on O365 authentication?

Tags: add-in, office-js, office-store

We are publishing an outlook add-in to office store, and this add-in is authenticated based on the O365 authentication, so once customer logins his o365 account, he could go to our service directly via our add-in. The question is whether we sign out the o365 account or not since we have failed for Add-in validation. There are two screenshots:

**[Failed if not sign out o365 account]**

[image]

**[Failed if sign out o365 account]**

[image]

We are a little confused about what we should do next step, could we just keep signing out of O365 account and add a note: we are authenticated by O365 authentication or could we just remove the Signout since our add-in is O365 authentication based?

Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the sign out might not be a good idea, unless you actually don't want that feature available to your users. I guess your problem might be that a session or local identifier is stored on the client and it is automatically being logged in when the add-in opens again when sign-out was pressed ( from what i understand ).

If you are using OAuth 2.0 standard, what you should try: Find the stored session either locally or server side and remove it when the user logs out. Also you could log out the user out with the Microsoft sign-out url see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code

If you are using the SSO of Office, what you'd want to do is just remove the local side storage that holds the tokens, and then show the user the log in page ( with a button to log them in again ) for info about SSO see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, I totally agree with you it is bad to remove the sign-out function. Now our trouble is when we sign out by the url "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout", the user will be signed out automatically in the Office. You know the office addin is running in the panel of office we cloud also technically call it "IFrame". So when we sign out the user it will have the result in the report of Microsoft.  We could get the authenticated code from its parent window, So i don't think  we could just sign out the user of the session in the Iframe. Any idea? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Darren, are you guys using : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins to authenticate users?

Comment: @Darren Aside of that, what you could do is when you sign out the user from the add-in and redirect them to the "Landing page/first page” and then place a button that says "Sign in" where the user can re-sign in (re-grab the token and authenticate the user on your end). I guess that would be elegant enough as a sign-in/sign-out solution